# Get DataTable settings based on table ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have used JQuery datatable and i have created common method in order to customize all grids.

```
function GridCommon(id) {
    this.ControlId = id;


    var columns = [];
    var service = "";
    var zeroRecords = "";
    var processingStr = "";
    var jsonVal = ko.toJSON(this.ControlId).replace(/'/g, "\\'");
    var obj = "{'DataTablename':'" + jsonVal + "'}";
    var recLength = 10;
    var sortColumn = 0;
    var sortOrder = "ASC";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Service/DataGridService.asmx/GetTableSttings',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: obj,
        async: false,
        success: function (arg) { //call successfull   
            Result = arg.d;
            var val = JSON.parse(Result);
            columns = MapColumnDefsDbTableToGrid(JSON.parse(val.ColumnDefinition));
            columnList = val.ColumnDefinition;
            service = val.AjaxSource;
            zeroRecords = val.NoRecordsText;
            processingStr = val.ProcessingText;
            recLength = val.DisplayLength;
            prametersList = JSON.parse(val.ParameterList);
            sortColumn = val.initialSortColumnNumber;
            sortOrder = val.initialSortColumnOrder;
        },
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });

    this.ColumnDefs = columns;
    this.ServiceMethod = service;
    this.NoRecordsText = zeroRecords;
    this.ProcessingText = processingStr;
    this.RecordLength = recLength;
    this.InitialSortColumnNumber = sortColumn;
    this.InitialSortColumnOrder = sortOrder;
}
```

I am using this method to initialize several grids. My problem occurs with pagination. when doing pagination it does not get correct grid settings **oSettings**.(it's get last initialize grid settings.) Is there any way i can get datatable settings using table id? 
or is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: That call to your service is async and the success handler of the ajax request will fire later then the initialization of the object's values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Able to find solution for this.

```
 var newSettings = $("#currentGrid").dataTable().fnSettings();
```

Addtional :

If need to get current grid ID can take it as follows.

```
var currentGrid = oSettings.sTableId;
```